# How to insert data in postgresql using for loop?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert, generate-series

I would like to know how to insert data in postgresql using for loop?

I want to insert 1 to 1000 in row of id..

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 87):

Please try below code to insert values in tables using for loop.

```
do $$
begin
for r in 1..1000 loop
insert into schema_name.table_name(id) values(r);
end loop;
end;
$$;
```

Comment: God bless the fruit of your mother's womb

Answer (score 23):

Use [`generate_series`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-srf.html):

```
INSERT INTO tableName (id) SELECT * FROM generate_series(1, 1000);
```

Comment: is there a reason to avoid it? @Evan Carroll

Comment: @EvanCarroll In case you want to generate some test data, or want to performance benchmark, you can always use this.

Comment: Yes, it's good for test data. Reasons to avoid it -- if it's a real ID column, it should be an identity column. If it's numbers on output you should use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER ()`, etc.

Comment: this one's faster than the loop